# What exactly is being used when I upload an download in Chrome's lower download bar that has been removed from local system?

Tags: google-chrome, upload

What exactly is being examined when I upload an download (from the Chrome lower download bar) that has been removed (from my local machine) to, say, VirusTotal?
Example...

1. Download the dummy PDF file from https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf (or any other PDF file from anywhere else you're comfortable). Make sure you have the lower popup downloads bar enabled in Chrome.
2. Delete the downloaded file from you local system
3. From the lower download bar in Chrome, drag the downloaded file (that we've deleted locally) into the [VirusTotal UI](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/) to upload it (**note this is not private**). See the image example below...

[image]
The actual analysis on VirusTotal can be found here: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855/detection

Notice that *something* does get uploaded (as opposed to the nothing that I would think there would be). What is this exactly and how is it created? (Note: I am using an Ubuntu 18.04.5 machine)

(I really don't know if this or another SO community would be the right place for this question, so if you think this would be better served being migrated then please LMK)

Answer (score 1):

I have traced the message sent to VirusTotal, and the answer to your question is:
Nothing is sent.

Chrome sends the "file" as empty, meaning zero bytes, and VirusTotal dutifully
indicates that no viruses were found in those zero bytes.

Some programming checks are missing here, both in Chrome and VirusTotal,
but what you get is what happens between two non-intelligent programs.